# im trying to learn JavaScript, how can i make a certain section of doc.data clickable a new link

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code and I want the geolocation to be able to open a new window that directs to the data that it stores example: it only shows as text in (geolocation:https://www.google.com/maps/place/7.9911209,125.1280968)

here is my code :

```js
const emergencyList = document.querySelector('#emergency-list');
const form = document.querySelector('#add-form');

function renderEmergencyList(doc) {

  let li = document.createElement('li');
  let name = document.createElement('span');
  let accidenttype = document.createElement('span');
  let geoloc = document.createElement('a');
  let cross = document.createElement('div');

  li.setAttribute('data-id', doc.id);
  name.textContent = "Name: " + doc.data().user.fullname;
  accidenttype.textContent = "Accident Type: " + doc.data().accident_type;
  geoloc.textContent = "Geo Location: " + doc.data().geo_point;
  cross.textContent = 'x';

  li.appendChild(name);
  li.appendChild(accidenttype);
  li.appendChild(geoloc);
  li.appendChild(cross);

  emergencyList.appendChild(li);

  // deleting data
  geoloc.addEventListener('click', function() {
    window.open(geo_point);
  })

  cross.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    let id = e.target.parentElement.getAttribute('data-id');
    db.collection('Emergency Message').doc(id).delete()
  })

}
```

```html
<div id="content" class="content">
  <a ul id="emergency-list" onclick="changeLink()">
         <a href="" id="mylink"">Geolocation</a>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Here is the output, I want the geolocation to be clickable into new window that refers to the link
Name: undefined
Accident Type:  it stores
Geo Location: https://www.google.com/maps/place/7.9911209,125.1280968 * it only shows as text in *

Comment: Can you explain what is not working with all that code? What have you tried to solve your requirement?

Comment: it works but i want to have a clickable list view and pass the data to new window

Comment: my code would always somehow appear as text and not link

Comment: "I want" isn't a problem or question, or an error message. I assume you're asking about this because your code isn't doing what you expected it to. But for us to help you, you need to give a more direct description about what is going on. You can tell us what you want the code to do, sure, but also we need to know what it is currently doing instead. This should include any results from the debugging work you've done so far (and if you haven't done any yet, then please go and do some so you can narrow down the problem for us).

Comment: You didn't set `href` attribute on `geoloc`, there's only `textContent` in this code